# ¿Cómo numerar renglones en jtextarea?

Tags: java

tengo un proyecto que deberá realizar un análisis léxico, sintáctico y semántico, pero en el `JTextField` no se como hacer que quede numerado para que a la hora de ejecutar el analizador este diga en que renglón encontró el problema

[image: captura de pantalla]

Logrando algo como lo que presenta por ejemplo sublime text
[image: Sublime Text]

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy amplia, ya que no has aportado código para ver qué estás intentando hacer y desde cero no es una tarea trivial, pero permíteme que te oriente: Tienes que colocar un componente al lado, un JPanel por ejemplo, que muestre los números. Si además quieres que sea scrollable, tendrás que meter ambos en un JScrollPanel. Tienes una solución ya hecha [aquí](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/23/text-component-line-number/)

Comment: Esa publicación ya la había intentando seguir pero `TextLineNumber tln = new TextLineNumber(textPane);` me marcaba error, diciendo que no encuentra `TextLineNumbre` y no entiendo si es un algo que hay que descargar, y estoy trabajando con el diseño grafico que da netbeans, es lo que nos enseñaron en la escuela, igual te paso el codigo en un pastebin para que lo revises
[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/UX9a6HKR)

Comment: En el enlace que te pasé viene a su ven un enlace al código de esa clase, por eso te decía que tenías una solución ahí: me refería a una [implementación](http://www.camick.com/java/source/TextLineNumber.java) que resuelve el problema

Comment: gracias @pablo-lozano no había visto ese archivo .java, lo bajo y hago pruebas, cualquier cosa sigo dando lata un rato mas.

Comment: Funciona como debería, era lo que estaba necesitando ni mas ni menos, del código que dan de ejemplo picandole a todo encontré cuales eran las variables que tenía que renombrar y cuales asignaciones eliminarlas, te agradezco mucho